# How to create a button on click to move to next page (RecyclerView + ViewPager2)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Here are the adapter class and I am trying to create a button on click listener within OnCreateViewHolder to click and move on to the next page of the Pager2ViewHolder and nothing seems to work for me.

I really appreciate any help that will be given.

```
package com.example.apitestquiz.viewmodel

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.core.view.children
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.apitestquiz.R
import com.example.apitestquiz.model.QuestionModelItem

class ViewPagerAdapter(private var list:List<QuestionModelItem>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.Pager2ViewHolder>() {
    private lateinit var radioButton: RadioButton

    private var score:IntArray = IntArray(list.size)
    private var answerCorrect = Array(list.size){""}
    private var count:IntArray = IntArray(list.size)

    inner class Pager2ViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        //item_page content
        val radioGroup: RadioGroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2)
        val textView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textQuestion2)
        val buttonRight: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonRight)
        val buttonLeft: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft)
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewPagerAdapter.Pager2ViewHolder {
        return Pager2ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_page,parent,false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewPagerAdapter.Pager2ViewHolder, position:Int){
        holder.textView.text = list[position].question
        val answers = getAnswerCollection(list,position)

        holder.radioGroup.children.forEachIndexed { index, view ->
            radioButton = view as RadioButton
            radioButton.text = answers[index]
        }

        holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
            val radio:RadioButton = holder.radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId)
            if(radio.text.toString().equals(answerCorrect[position],true)){
                if (score[position]<=0)
                    count[position] = 1
                    score[position] = 1
            }else{
                if (score[position]>=0){
                    count[position] = 1
                    score[position] = 0
                }
            }
        }

//        holder.buttonRight.setOnClickListener {
//            val context = holder.itemView.context
//            if(count.sum() == 5){
//            val intent = Intent (context, EndActivity::class.java)
//            intent.putExtra("scoreFin",score.sum().toString())
//            context.startActivity(intent)
//            }else{ Toast.makeText(context,"Answer All Question",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
//        }

        when(position){
            0-> {
                holder.buttonLeft.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                holder.buttonRight.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.buttonRight.text = "Next"

            }
            4 ->{
                holder.buttonLeft.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.buttonRight.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.buttonRight.text = "Finish"
                holder.buttonLeft.text = "Previous"
            }
            else -> {
                holder.buttonLeft.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.buttonRight.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.buttonRight.text = "Next"
                holder.buttonLeft.text = "Previous"
            }
        }

    }

    private fun getAnswerCollection(x:List<QuestionModelItem>,y:Int): MutableList<String> {
        answerCorrect[y] = x[y].correctAnswer //Getting answer from API
        val answerWrong:List<String> = x[y].incorrectAnswers
        val answerCollect = answerWrong + x[y].correctAnswer  //Getting answer collections and shuffling
        val answerShuffle = answerCollect.toMutableList()
        answerShuffle.shuffle()

        return answerShuffle
    }

}
```

I have tried some animation but that does not scroll/swipe to the next activity only a blank page

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look into the documentation of ViewPager2 https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2 you can see that has setCurrentItem method. I suggest you add a callback for clicking on button that has to move to the next page. It will look something like this:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(private var list:List<QuestionModelItem>, val onButtonRightClick: (Int) -> Unit))
```

And in buttonRight onClickListener you call that callback with current index:

```
buttonRight.setOnClickListener {
    onButtonRightClick(position)
}
```

The last step is to properly add a callback to the adapter, so in your Fragment or Activity wherever you have your adapter you must create it in that way:

```
val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(list) {
      viewPager2.setCurrentItem(it + 1)
   }
```

I made an assumption that your ViewPagerAdapter can be referenced as viewPager2.